# differential of the riemannian exponential

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a riemannian manifold with exponential $exp$ and denote its inverse by $log$ and the parallel transport by $\Gamma$. Assuming that $X$ is a curve on $M$, it holds trivially that $exp_{x^*}(log_{x^*}(X(t)))=X(t)$, which implies that $d(exp_{x^*})(log_{x^*}(X))(\frac{d}{dt}log_{x^*}(X))=\dot X$, after differentiating. I would like to prove a discrete analogue of the previous formula, i.e. $d(exp_{x^*})(log_{x^*}(x_{k+1}))(log_{x^*}(x_{k+1})-log_{x^*}(x_k))= \Gamma_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}} log_{x_k}(x_{k+1})$ (or something similar). I know a result which states that $d(exp_a)(log_a(b))(log_a(b))=-log_b(a)$, so I can evaluate the first part of the quantity in the left hand side, but I have no idea how to treat the second one. Any help?